# What can I do to maintain equal size and strength in both hands?

Tags: strength, strength-training, workout-types, biceps

I m 25 years old and I m going to gym for 3 days in a week. When I workout for biceps in heavy weight, my partner realized that my left hand is exerting more strength than my right hand. When I look in front of mirror, I also see the difference in both hands. I can also feel the difference that my left hand is more tight and my right hand is looser.

What can I do to ensure that both hands' size and strength are equal?

Comment: It might help to know which exercises you are doing, and if they are unilateral (one arm at a time) or bilateral (both arms).

Comment: Standing barbell curls,Cable machine,Dumbbells.. In dumbell one arm at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to cut all barbell exercises and dedicate yourself to Dumbbell work for the next 2-3 months.  Everyone always has a dominant arm or leg (throw, kick, etc with).  Work on some grip training (holds 2 25-45pd plates with your fingers for time for e.g.), dedicate yourself to DB exclusive work (curls, pullovers, flys, bench, incline, raises, tricep, etc. 2 x week or so).  To really make progress emphasize your weaknesses and don't let ego get in the way.  Go full range of motion opposed to heavy weight and don't cheat the exercise with improper form.